# Java Listeners как поступить?

Tags: java, eclipse

При разработке программы на вышеуказанной языке я столкнулся с таким вопросом: где лучше объявлять слушателей для визуальных элементов?

Суть моей задачи такова: разработка инженерного калькулятора. Я примерно прикинул, на фрейме будет размещено не менее 50-ти кнопок

класс ClInitVisualElements объявляет и в своих процедурах инициализирует форму с 50-тью кнопками на ней.

я зашел в тупик при создании слушателей для этих элементов окна. Понимаю, что объявить слушателей можно:

- В конструкторе (но этот вариант я сразу отбрасываю) так как мне не один человек объяснял, что в конструкторе должен быть только вызов какой-то одной процедуры
- В отдельной процедуре класса ClInitVisualElements
- В отдельном методе какого другого класса, например, `CInitFrameListeners` и вызвать этот метод при создании визуальных элементов

Если у кого есть опыт по разработке программ JAVA, то подскажите, мне, пожалуйста, как было бы правильно поступить с профессиональной точки зрения организации кода?

Заранее благодарен.

Comment: Классический же пример паттерна [Observer](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/observer). Непонятно, зачем свой велосипед придумывать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

все очень просто:

предположим у вас есть следующие классы:

```
class CalcEvent {...} // базовый класс для ивентов калькулятора (будете от него наследоватся для разных типов ивентов, напр ввод команды/ввод значения)

class CalcFrame // предполагается что это класс вашего окна калькулятора
{
    private CalcEngine engine = null;

    public abstract void generateDummyEvent ()
    {
         // generate event
         engine.handleEvent ( new CalcEvent() )    ;
    }

}

class CalcEngine implements CalcEventListener // класс который обрабатывает и распределяет ивенты
{
     private List<CalcEventListener> listeners = new LinkedList<CalcEventListener>();

     // ... другие поля/методы...

     public void handleEvent () 
     {
         for ( CalcEventListener l : listeners )
         {
             l.handleEvent(e);
         }    
     }
}

interface CalcEventListener
{
    public void handleEvent(CalcEvent event);
}
```

где engine и будет единственным слушателем вашего "калькулятора". это будет первое использование шаблона обсервер.

а далее внутри самого engine делаете обработку и распределение ивентов в зависимости от того как удобнее: if/switch/шаблоном observer

**UPDATE: сделал пример более детальным**

Comment: Я решил организовать на каждый элемент отдельный обработчик, это поможет мне избежать от 1 до 50 (возможно и больше) операций проверок в дефлтном случае. Это позволит мне сэкономить машинное время (хотя несколько миллисекунд, но для меня это приоритет) но наверняка под выполнение программы потребуется выделить больше оперативки.

Моя проблема заключается в том. что я незнаю где выполнять объявления слушателей для этих 50 элементов: выполнить в методе класса, который отвечает за построение графики, или выполнить в методе отдельного класса, который будет отвечать только за объявление слушателей

Comment: вы видимо вообще не поняли суть идеи. я предлагаю вам повешать на каждую кнопку генерацию ивента после чего он будет обрабатыватся engine классом. а уже в класе engine вы будете распределять кому обработать следующий ивент, - 50 ифов и свитчей

Comment: я понял вашу идею, но она не решает проблему выполнения большого количества проверок, поэтому для каждого элемента будет создано отдельного слушателя (или столько, сколько потребуется) как мне посоветовали в предыдущей теме

http://hashcode.ru/questions/63724/%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%8B-java

Comment: проблема заключалась в том, что я знал где лучше описать эти 50 слушателей.
на другом ресурсе мне посоветовали слушателя элемента описывать там же, где он инициализируется и задается его параметр. так наверное и сделаю. Спасибо за вашу помощь.

Comment: не думаю что есть смысл создавать много разных обработчиков, считаю что вам нужно всего лишь 2 (для начала):
1) обрабатывает ввод данных
2) обрабатывает ввод команды

вы или вводите данные или вводите какую-то команду чтоб сделать действие над данными